# enter only when the button is enabled

Tags: protractor

i am trying to check if a button is enabled and then input a value and submit. 
I have used if else loop to check this. but the execution never enters the loop. Below is the code used.

```
await this.sendButton.isEnabled().then(async function(enabled) {
    if(enabled) {
        await $('.input').sendKeys('abc');
await $('.send-btn').click();
await  $$('.value' ).getText().then(async function(itemList) {
await expect(itemList).toContain('abc');
});enter code here
}
else {
console.log('button is disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

enabled runs without if statement?

```
await this.sendButton.isEnabled().then(async function (enabled) {
    await $('.input').sendKeys('abc');
    await $('.send-btn').click();
    await $$('.value').getText().then(async function (itemList) {
        await expect(itemList).toContain('abc');
    });
```

}

You check the button is enabled or disabled - isEnabled - so at first glance, the if statement is unnecessarry, and you can write another expect, the disabled state.

```
.isEnabled().toBe(false).then(.....)
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your comment. I still dont get it to work . i have tried some thing like 

await this.sendButton.isEnabled().toBe(true).then(async function (enabled) {
    await $('.input').sendKeys('abc');
    await $('.send-btn').click();

Comment: or am i missing your comment ?

Comment: it('should update the value when buton is enabled ', async function() 
{
    browser.get(url);
    await this.sendButton.isEnabled().then(async function(enabled) {
      if(enabled) {
          await $('.input').sendKeys('abc');
    await $('.send-btn').click();
    await  $$('.value' ).getText().then(async function(itemList) {
    await expect(itemList).toContain('abc');
  });
  }
  else {
    console.log('button is disabled');
  }
  });

Comment: I guess you can change it the "if statement" to "toBeTruthy()

it('should update the value when button is enabled ', async function () {
 browser.get(url)
  .then(this.sendButton.isEnabled().toBeTruthy())
  .then(async function () {
   await $('.input').sendKeys('abc');
   await $('.send-btn').click();
   await $$('.value').getText()
    .then(async function (itemList) {
     await expect(itemList).toContain('abc');
    });
  })
});

Comment: And another think, Do you have to use anyway the async functions, or, you can change all from "await" to "then.(----)"  but that's just a tip.

Comment: I first tried toBeTruthy and toBe(true). but both returned  isEnabled(...).toBeTruthy is not a function and isEnabled(...).toBe(true)is not a function

Comment: If you check just, the button isEnabled.toBeTrue, it was passed? Without SendKeys and click(),

Comment: Not in all cases. When the button is not enabled it fails with  invalid element state error

Comment: Any progress ever since? I thinking about that, and I've an idea, if change example the containt to Equal ==> 

it('should update the value when button is enabled ', function () {
  this.sendButton.isEnabled().toBeTruthy()
  .then(function() {
   $('.input').sendKeys('abc');
   $('.send-btn').click();
   $$('.value').getText()
    .then(function(itemList) {
     expect(itemList).toEqual('abc');
    });
  })
});

Comment: No no progress yet. I am stuck there. I cannot check the condition . Thanks for your input. I cannot verify with Equal , as the list has many elements and the test would fail